# How does the $html.appendTo($parentEl) work internally to allow listeners to be attached before the $html is in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I always thought that listeners can only be attached to elements in the DOM. If an element was dynamically added then we need to reattach the listeners or attach listeners to a parent element (bubbling) in the first place. However when I use `.appendTo()` I can somehow attach listeners to an element that is not in the DOM and it still works. How does `appendTo` change things? Am I making a grave mistake using this method which I will regret later?

Code:

```js
var $html = $("<div class='someElNotInDom'>random text</div>");
attachSomeListeners($html); // ex. click event listener etc.
var $parentEl = $(".someElementInDom").eq(0);
$html.appendTo($parentEl); 
// all the listeners work. Why?
```

Comment: By the looks of your code you have created the element and attached the events to it - it doesn't matter if it is in the dom or not as the element is created, your code should also work with append.  If your element doesn't exist when you try to attach the events - that's when you use event delegation

Comment: The element does not have to be attached to the DOM to have event handlers *attached* to it. It does have to be in the DOM for any event to be *raised* on it.

Comment: thanks pete and Rory, thanks for busting a bad assumption. So the object just needs to be of type document node and then it doesn't matter?